# Concatenation of data based on Values in different Column

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation, udf

Require help with Concatenateif function

I have data on Column A & Column B - for all the unique values in Column A

I am looking to concatenate the corresponding values in Column B and then the result to be displayed in Column C

for Example: C2 is the Concatenated value of B1 & B2 separated by Commas

C5 is the Concatenated value of B5 to B7 separated by Commas

[image]

Comment: The question as written is not clear in terms of what you want as a *result* of the input you have provided. That said, it's very possible a formula will work more easily than VBA code.

Comment: What version of Excel? Excel 2016 has the TEXTJOIN function. @ScottHoltzman OP wants to join the Products for each Supplier. For example `103, 680, 241` in `C2`

Comment: i don't think amendment required on the useful code u found, its quite universal already

Comment: try use it, if only u have an error, then only ask the error here

Comment: So what do you have so far?

Comment: I have found this code - however wondering where condition should be input or changed http://www.exceltips.nl/concatenateif-function-for-excel/

Comment: Also, in the future make sure you post your sample data in the post and not a picture. A lot of people can't see it because the image host gets blocked.

Answer (score 0):

with this oversimplified UDF:

```
Public Function join(Delimiter, values)
    For Each value In values
        If value > "" Then
            If join > "" Then join = join & Delimiter
            join = join & value
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

you can use an array formula like this:

```
{=join(",",IF(A2:A5=A2,B2:B5,""))}
```

---

or with some of the TEXTJOIN UDF [substitutes](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2016/06/07/textjoin-function/):

```
{=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A2:A5=A2,B2:B5,""))}
```